# unable to pass the required argument to a function inside jsx of react render()

Tags: reactjs

Basically, I want to pass the value associated with span element to the function UpdateSelectedNumbers(). However, if I create an array of span elements using for loop the onClick eventhandler ( UpdateSelectedNumbers) is always called with value 9. This is not the case when i use the map function. Can someone explain why this happens

```
const stars = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var temp = [];
for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
    temp.push(<span className={getClass(i+1)} onClick={()=>props.UpdateSelectedNumbers(i+1)}>{i+1} </span>)
}
return (
     <div>
     {stars.map(x => <span className={getClass(x)} onClick={()=> props.UpdateSelectedNumbers(x)}>{x}</span>)}
     {temp}
     </div>
    )
```

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var` for `i`. [Why this works is explained in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav).

Comment: Thanks scoping was the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `var` is scoped to the nearest function, all your `()=>props.UpdateSelectedNumbers(i+1)` functions will get the final value of `i`, which is `8`.

You could instead use `let` which is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, so each iteration of the loop will have its own value.